# How do I create a list from the input of a user? w/Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, input

I've been trying to make a function that uses a number previously determined from another function (which I have that part of the code working) and asks the user to give an amount of names equal to the number previously determined. Here's the code:

```
def getNames(myNumOfTypes):
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    print("Now, enter all the names of the people getting a type:")

    names = []
    for i in range(0, myNumOfTypes):
        name = input("-")
        names.append(name)
    return names[i]
```

Later, when I print the names list, it's only a list of the last input I entered... I never really learned for loops and lists, and now I'm trying to use both and it's rough. for reference, myNumOfTypes was a variable I used earlier, but because the numbers have to be the same I just recycled it.

Comment: `return names` ?

Comment: I return it, out of the function to later use it... This might just be an issue of not knowing how to return a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added a `[i]` on the last line which gets the value of a specific index, you need to remove it to make the last line become:

```
    return names
```

Comment: When I do that, it says that the variable i wasn't used

Comment: @AlexDoiron What ya mean?

Comment: When I have the last line as 
return names

Comment: I get an error saying the the "i" in " for i in range" is an unused variable

Comment: @AlexDoiron Try changing `for i in range(0, myNumOfTypes):` to `for _ in range(0, myNumOfTypes):`

Comment: It said I can only do that in five minutes, I just tried, but I'll try again in a few minutes

Comment: @AlexDoiron Oh yeah, i know